# Running ipynb file, but can't import a certain module

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, development-environment, amazon-sagemaker

l'am running a ipynb file on sagemaker, however the error of occurs.
l have used 'pip install tqdm' in terminals to install the tqdm so l've no idea what's happening. Is it running in a different environment?
Thanks for any answer.

[error report from my ipynb file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bO6zS.png)

[what l've done in terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5tP1J.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a possibility you may be executing "pip" in a different environment.

Try executing "!pip install tqdm" or "!pip3 install tqdm" as a code cell in the Sagemaker document itself.

Comment: l  solve the problem this way. thanks